# Light not visible on one side in a room rendered using three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render a scene of a room with multiple lights inside it. The weird part is that the effects of the lights is visible on three sides of the room but the right side of the room doesn't reflect any light and is pitch black. The material on all sides of the room is same and is THREE.MeshPhongMaterial. I used THREE.DoubleSide as well but it didn't help.

Am I missing something?

Following is the code for loading the room.

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(model, function(geometry, materials){
    for(i=0;i<materials.length;i++){
        materials[i].shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
        materials[i].wrapAround = true;
    }

    var jsmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    jsmesh.scale.set(100,100,100);

    jsmesh.position.y=159;
    jsmesh.position.x=177;
    jsmesh.position.z=-180;
    jsmesh.name = model;
    jsmesh.receiveShadow = true;
    jsmesh.overdraw = true;

    scene.add(jsmesh);

});
```

pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5 , 800);
scene.add(pointLight);

I am adding few point lights to this mesh (which is a room). The effects of light come on left, top and front walls. But the right wall is black.

Comment: you could try creating a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` and apply it to the loaded mesh, just to see if the problem persists. it could be possible the material loaded has some errors or mistakes in it. i dont see anything strange in the code.

Comment: Didn't help. I see that the material is getting applied properly.

Comment: I experimented with a few materials and custom geometry and figured out that material on that particular wall in the mesh was faulty. I replaced it with custom geometry and it worked. Thanks.